# AWS - Trying to Create a Policy - Resource field not valid

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a simple policy using AWS. I am doing the AWS IoT tutorial for their sdk, and it clearly says to create a policy to allow an unauthorized user access to the service:[image]

I created a pool, added the id to my constants.swift file, and then try to create a policy with my pool ARN and i get the error saying the resource is invalid:[image]

I then tried going to my Iot Test console and registered a "thing" who's resource tag works and got an arn, but this is not what the tutorial is telling me to do.

Can anyone clarify how to get this credential?

Thanks!

E: All I am trying to do is to connect to my AWS IoT console. Very simple stuff. It seems like the only thing left to do is "make sure that the policy attached to unauthenticated role has permissions to access the required AWS IoT APIs"

E: Here is the ARN I entered [image]

Do any of you know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the ARN that you entered?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I posted the image of the ARN I entered. It is from my pool ARN

Comment: Why are you entering a Cognito ARN into an IoT policy. Did some documentation suggest you do this? Normally, the ARN relates to the service for which you are creating a policy (eg for S3, refer to an S3 bucket).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , I am following the documentation from image 1 in my post from the AWS IOT IOS SDK. Here is a link to it https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoT-Sample/Swift. It says "In the Amazon Cognito console, use Amazon Cognito to create a new identity pool. Obtain the PoolID constant. Make sure that the policy attached to the unauthenticated role has permissions to access the required AWS IoT APIs" Which I don't understand how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample policy from the [AWS IoT documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html) that allows unauthenticated Amazon Cognito identities to publish messages over HTTP on any topic:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iot:Connect",
            "iot:Publish",
            "iot:Subscribe",
            "iot:Receive",
            "iot:GetThingShadow",
            "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
            "iot:DeleteThingShadow​"
        ],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }]
}
```

> To allow unauthenticated Amazon Cognito identities to publish MQTT messages over HTTP on topic1 in your account, attach the following policy to your Amazon Cognito identity pool role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["iot:Publish"],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:topic/topic1"]
    }]
}
```

It seems that you can attach these policies to the Role used to grant permissions to unauthenticated users.

Comment: Thank you very much this is it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note :
For S3 policy sample correct Amazon Resource Name (ARN), which u can replace by your domain name

```
arn:aws:s3:::coolsite.com/*
```